# Yet another jQuery autocomplete thread

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, autocomplete, laravel-blade

I am trying to figure out what's wrong with my code (Laravel5 project).

So far I have:
master.blade.php

```
<!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 and jQuery UI-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="{{asset("patho/to/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.js")}}"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

the master view is preloaded in any view, it serves as a header and footer wrapper. Note that I obfuscated the local path to jQuery script, it's real and it's loaded and it works.

Included in one of my CRUD views:
create.blade.php

```
{!! Form::select('league_id',[], Request::old('league_id'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'league_name')) !!}
<script src="{{ asset('js/tips.js') }}">
```

And in my tips.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataSource = ['test1', 'test2'];
    $('#league_name').autocomplete(
        {
            source: dataSource
        }
    );
});
```

I also tried with:

```
var dataSource = [{value: 'test1', name: 'test1'}]
```

Yet it still does not work at all, no console errors displayed either.

Any clues?

Edit: following michaelbahr's suggestion:

the autocomplete widget doesn't execute at all, the resulting select dropdown I get is just an empty one. No items, no search box from the widget. A plain, empty select:

```
<select class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" id="league_name" name="league_id" autocomplete="off"></select>
```

Comment: Please specify WHAT is not working. Meaning: What should your code do. (for clarification)

Comment: Rating it negatively doesn't help me either...

Comment: Do you think I rated it down? I didn't.

Comment: Sorry, I am not saying it's you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work that way. Autocomplete needs an input (text) field to work. If you wanna have a select, you can do something like [this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

But, if you already have an array, you don't need autocomplete, you can simply use jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataSource = ['test1', 'test2'];
    var league = $('#league_name');
    $.each(dataSource, function(index, value){
        league.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to solve the problem (input instead of select), how silly was I...